# Number validation in required field validator

Tags: asp.net, validation

Is it possible to put Number validation in required field validator in asp.net text box?

Answer (score 73):

You should use the [CompareValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.aspx), for example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server />
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt" Type="Integer"
   Operator="DataTypeCheck" ErrorMessage="Value must be an integer!" />
```

This is the most natural choice if you want a simple data type check. Otherwise if you want to verify a range use the [RangeValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.aspx) suggestions. If you need a certain pattern use the [RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx).

Note that you'll want to add a [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx) as well since some validators will allow blank entries.

Comment: I attached this validator to ValidationGroup="Form". But I still able to submit the form without raising validation error. Any suggestions??

Comment: @Dr.MAF did you also add a `RequiredFieldValidator` per the last line? It prevents blank entries.

Comment: Yes. Upon submit, RequiredValidators fires correctly if the the textbox is blank, but the CompareValidator does not fire if the entry is alphabet.

Comment: Ok, ok. I found it out. I have a typo. The ValidationGroup="From" instead of "Form".

Answer (score 7):

Actually you only need a regularexpression validator for this purpose with    `ValidationExpression = "^\d+?$"`

Comment: * `ValidationExpression = @"^\d+?$"`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use a RangeValidator attached to that textbox, setting Type to Integer or wathever.

[RangeValidator class on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f70d09xt(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: You can also you a Regex Validator with \d+ as the pattern: http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/Validation-by-Control/Avalid5digitzipcode.htm

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is using the RegexpValidator and adding a regular expression that makes sure there's 1 or more digits in it, something like:

```
RegularExpressionValidator regexpvalidator = new RegularExpressionValidator(); 
regexpvalidator.ID = "RegularExpressionValidator1"; 
regexpvalidator.ValidationExpression = "\d+"; 
regexpvalidator.ControlToValidate = "YourControl"; 
regexpvalidator.ErrorMessage = "Please specify a digit"; 
regexpvalidator.SetFocusOnError = true;
```

Comment: No, validators other than RequiredFieldValidator (and maybe CustomValidator) will ignore empty inputs.

Answer (score 2):

No, a RequiredFieldValidator can only verify that the field contains something.

If you want to verify that the field only contains digits, you can use a RegularExpressionValidator with the pattern `"\d+"`.

Answer (score 2):

A RequiredFieldValidator only checks if the field is filled in. It doesn't care what with.

You will need an extra CompareValidator with it's Operator set to DataTypeCheck and it's Type set to Integer.
Note you need both: the CompareValidator will ignore an empty input.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RangeValidator ControlToValidate="tb" Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

Comment: This throws an exception related to `MaximumValue` not being specified.