# How do I validate a textbox to only contain numbers?

Tags: vb.net, validation, controls

If the user enters non-numeric and numeric values in a textbox, how do I keep only the numeric part?

Comment: Have you looked at MSDN for this already? Did you not find anything that serves your purpose? IMO, StackOverflow should add a category to close the question as "OP doesn't want to take any effort".

Comment: It is possible he is just that new.  It takes just a little experience to learn that Google can find all of this for you.  And a little more experience to learn the base terminology to actually find anything useful.  But granted, this is more likely just a case of lazy.

Comment: This sort of question is perfectly valid on SO.

Comment: Just to be clear the question originally asked was not a straight up validation type question. As it was asked it required manipulating the data entered not simply accepting or rejecting it. Since the OP is not apparently a native english speaker, simple validation *may* be sufficient, but until there is clarification I have edited it to more clearly state what was originally asked.

Comment: is this meant for Winforms or WPF?

Comment: IMO it's a perfectly valid SO question, but is hard to answer without more details.

Comment: Why do you all waste your time saying it should be somewhere else (other than the various stackoverflow sites) Just don't waste everyone's time and just answer the question!

Answer (score 3):

Set the property "CausesValidation" to true.  Set your validation to accept only an int or whatever sort of number you are looking for.

Perhaps see: [Number validation in required field validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394505/number-validation-in-required-field-validator)

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegularExpressionValidator

Validate it against your control, with the validation Expression of {0:d} to permit only digits or {0:w} for letters and numbers as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could bind to the keydown event and if the key is not 0-9 set handled to true.